# How to create a button click counter meta box?

Tags: metabox, ajax, post-meta

I am trying to create button click counter meta box in a custom post type, but I can't get it to work. What I want to do is when a user click the submit button, then it will do `update_post_meta` in the background and display the value on the current screen by `echo` `get_post_meta` with ajax.

Here is my codes so far:

**Hooks the metabox function**

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_categories_box');
```

**Add metabox function**

```
function add_custom_categories_box() {  
 add_meta_box(
        'wpse_54822_sectionid',
        __( 'Page Attachments' ), 
        'wpse_54822_inner_custom_box',
        'indtablea', 'normal'
    );
}
```

**Meta box**

```
function wpse_54822_inner_custom_box(){
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#target').click(function() {
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
});

$('.submitmeplease').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $('#counter').html(function(i, val) {
        $.post({
            url: ajaxurl,
            action:"ak_attach",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {increment: true},
            success: function() { alert('Request has returned') }
        });
        return +val+1;
});
});
});
</script>
<?php
?>
<button id="target" type="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="output">10</div>

<div id="#counter">1</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitmeplease" value="Submit" />
<?php
}
```

**Ajax Response**

```
 // Response to ajax script
function ajaxResponse($post){  
$data = $_POST['submit'];
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'my_key', $data);
 }  
add_action('wp_ajax_ak_attach', 'ajaxResponse');
```

I can't figure out what is the string of the variable `$data` in the `ajaxResponse` function should be.

Could somebody walking me through on creating that button click counter in metabox?

Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

First of all output your javascript in like this is a worse practice. So it's a lot better if you create your javascript file and the enqueue it using `wp_enqueue_script` hooked `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.

```
function enqueue_my_ajax( $hook ) {
    if( 'post.php' != $hook && 'post-new.php' != $hook ) return;
    // if you use in theme use get_template_directori_uri to retrieve the url
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_ajax_script', plugins_url('/my_ajax_script.js', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_ajax' );
```

Second, when you use metabox and ajax is always a good idea use nonces. You can use `wp_nonce_field` to create an hidden nonce input in the metabox and the retrieve the value and post with ajax.

Check in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) for the functions named above for more info.

Regarding the problem, the post Id should be passed via ajax, or `ajaxResponse` cannot make use of it.

So the function that display your metabox should be:

```
function wpse_54822_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
  $current_count = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_increment_key', true) ? : 1;
  wp_nonce_field( 'increment_my_count', '_nonce_count' );
?>

<input type="hidden" id="_count" name="_count" value="<?php echo $current_count ? : 1; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="_postid" name="_postid" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
<div id="counter"><?php printf( 'Current Count: %d', $current_count ); ?></div>
<input type="button" name="button" class="button button-primary submitmeplease" value="<?php _e('Update'); ?>" />

<?php } ?>
```

Your javascript (in the my_ajax_script.js file enqueued as above) should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.submitmeplease').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nonce = $('input[name="_nonce_count"]').val();
    var count = $('#_count').val();
    var id = $('#_postid').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: { _nonce_count: nonce, action: 'update_my_count', _count: count, postid: id },
      success: function( data ) {
        if (data != '' && data != '0')
          $('#_count').val( data );
          $('#counter').html('Current Count: ' + data)
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Your `myUpdateCount` function shoud be:

```
function myUpdateCount() {
  if ( ! check_admin_referer( 'increment_my_count', '_nonce_count' ) ) die();
  $postid = isset( $_POST['postid'] ) && $_POST['postid'] ? $_POST['postid'] : null;
  if ( ! $postid ) die();
  if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts', $postid) ) die();
  $new_count = isset( $_POST['_count'] ) && $_POST['_count'] ? $_POST['_count'] + 1 : 1;
  update_post_meta($postid, '_increment_key', $new_count);
  die( (string)$new_count );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_update_my_count', 'myUpdateCount');
```

Comment: Hey.., Thank you very much, but I can't get it to update the database. Is there something I need to do to make it work? I had doing correction in this '$postid' to this '$post->ID' in 'get_post_meta($postid, 'increment_key', true);', since it's return error message.

Comment: I did, but I get this notice: "Notice: Undefined variable: postid in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\simpleajax\simpleajax.php on line 78"

Comment: Ok, my bad. You made correction in `wpse_54822_inner_custom_box` function, I was looking at `ajaxResponse` function. In `wpse_54822_inner_custom_box` you have to use $post->ID (I've corrected the code in answer) @AriSusanto

Comment: @AriSusanto, I tested my code and there was some typos and bugs. Now I've corrected and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Basically an ajax call within WordPress looks like this:

**The jQuery / JS script**:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl, // the URL where the data are submitted
  type: 'POST'  // the METHOD on how the data are submitted
  action: 'myaction', // the ACTION called to process the data
  data: { // the DATA sent to the server 
    submit: 'somevalue',
    postid: $('#postid').val() // You can store the post ID value in an hidden input text field within the function you use to diplay the content of your metabox.
  },
  success: function(data){
    //Do something with the DATA pushed from server
    console.log( data );
  }
});
```

**The server side**

```
// functions.php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'wpcf_process_data' );
function wpcf_process_data(){

  //I'm sending data via POST method so i look for this data in $_POST variable
  $submit = isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ? $_POST['submit'] : false;
  $postid =  isset( $_POST['postid'] ) ? $_POST['postid'] : false;   

  //Do something with the data, for example update post meta
  $update = update_post_meta( $postid, 'mykey', $submit )

  //echo the result, in order to send it to the ajax call. we know that if update_post_meta creates a new record, it returns the meta_id, if you update a value, it returns true and false on failure. in other words this the data pushed from the server.
  echo $update;

  //Every ajax call must die.. i know sounds creepy, but it has to be done
  die();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but how the `global $post` variable can be setted in  top of an ajax request? And how it should be linked to the post which send the request? Remember than ajax request is a completely new http request with no status mantaining from the page that send and the page that receive.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, it's true. I'm going to update the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do to achieve it! Hope this will be helpful for anyone who find it useful. This example works perfectly in my local server. I am not creating the nonce for security yet, though. So you need to find how to add the nonce if you want to use it on your live site.

**Meta Box Hook**

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_categories_box');

function add_custom_categories_box() {  
 add_meta_box(
        'wpse_54822_sectionid',
        __( 'Page Attachments' ), 
        'wpse_54822_inner_custom_box',
        'indtablea', 'normal'
    );
}
```

**Metabox Form**

```
function wpse_54822_inner_custom_box(){
global $post;
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_key', true); // Show result

//You need to give your form fields class name or id to connect them with jQuery.    
?>
    <br/>
    <button id="target" type="button">Click Me</button>
    <input type="text" name="submit" class="submitme" value="" placeholder="columns" />
    <input type="text" name="posid" class="posid" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
    <?php
    }
```

**Register and Enqueue The jQuery To Administration Screen**

I use traditional way to include the script to administration screen.

```
function enqueue_my_ajax( $hook ) {

    wp_register_script( 'my_ajax_script', plugins_url('/simpleajax/my_ajax_script.js') );
    wp_enqueue_script('my_ajax_script');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_ajax' );
```

**Ajax Response**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback($post_id) {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post['ID'];
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
    $potid = $_POST['postid']; // get this string's name and value from jQUery
        $subamit = $_POST['submit']; // get this string's name and value from jQuery 
        $subamit += 1; // plus 1 the value so the submitted data equal to the number of cliks.
    $update = update_post_meta($potid, 'my_key', $subamit); // Let's execute the data to our wordpress' database.

      echo $potid;
      echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

**jQuery Ajax**
This is the `my_ajax_script.js` file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#target').click(function(e) {
    var m = $('.submitme').val(); //get value of input field with class name "submitme"
    var pid = $('.posid').val(); //get value of input field with class name "posid"
    var sbmit = $('.submitme').val();
    $('.submitme').val(m*1+1); // Increment the input field's value named "submitme"        
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action', // Put this action name after wp_ajax hook  
        whatever: 1234,
        postid: pid, // get the post id to included in update_post_meta
        submit: sbmit // get the value to be submitted.
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) { // do the ajax
//Display the success response here if you want to do it!
    });
});

});
```

**Useful External Referrences:**

Ajax in Wordpress Plugin http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

jQUeryajax API documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

jQuery API documentation http://api.jquery.com/